# Como fazer busca e ordenação de TemplateFields em um GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basicamente, tenho uma tabela (GridView) em uma página aspx cujos dados estão definidos por TemplateFields. Por exemplo:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdProdutos">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Produto">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProduto" Text='<%# Eval("NomeProduto")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tipo">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTipo" Text='<%# Eval("TipoProduto")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preço">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPreco" Text='<%# Eval("PrecoProduto")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Os métodos usados no code behind são os seguintes:

```
RepositorioProdutos banco = new RepositorioProdutos();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        CarregarGridView();
    }
}

public void CarregarGridView()
{
    var produtos = banco.ObterProdutos();

    if (produtos != null)
    {
        grdProdutos.DataSource = produtos;
        grdProdutos.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Nenhum produto encontrado.");
    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber como poderia implementar uma busca por produtos (procurando um termo em qualquer campo) e como poderia implementar uma ordenação clicando no nome da coluna que eu gostaria de ordenar (como no Explorer do Windows), **sem precisar fazer uma nova consulta ao banco** (ou seja, sem precisar acessar o método `banco.ObterProdutos()` novamente).

**Obs.:** para a busca, estou considerando o uso de um textBox que será usado para inserir a palavra-chave da busca, e um botão que acionará a busca.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

São duas perguntas distintas, na minha opinião não é uma tarefa tão simples quando parece, portanto essa resposta não pretende ser definitiva, mas apenas tentar mostrar um ponto de partida.

Sobre o sorting:

O GridView possui um evento `OnSorting` que fornece um parâmetro com uma propriedade `SortExpression` que contém uma string normalmente com o nome do campo a ser ordenado.

Ocorre que com Linq não conseguimos ordernar os campos a partir de uma string, para isso precisamos de uma library System.Linq.Dynamic que permite utilizarmos strings em vez das lambda expressions.

Portanto, instale a library System.Linq.Dynamic pelo nuget, depois certifique-se de fazer referência no seu código:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
```

Agora altere seu gridView para aceitar sorting:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdProdutos" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gridView_Sorting" runat="server">
```

Nas colunas do gridView precisamos definir a SortExpression que informa por qual campos queremos ordenar:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Produto" SortExpression="Produto">
```

E no seu codebehind:

```
protected void grdProdutos_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    var gridView = (GridView)sender;

    for (int i = 0; i < gridView.Columns.Count; i++)
        if (gridView.Columns[i].SortExpression == e.SortExpression)
            if (e.SortExpression.EndsWith(" desc"))
                gridView.Columns[i].SortExpression = e.SortExpression.Replace(" desc", "");
            else
                gridView.Columns[i].SortExpression = e.SortExpression + " desc";


    gridView.DataSource = banco.ObterProdutos().OrderBy(e.SortExpression);        
    gridView.DataBind();
}
```

Lembrando que o Dynamic Linq funciona com tipos `IQueryable<T>`, portanto se seu método `ObterProdutos` retorna um `IEnumerable<T>` modifique o mesmo, provavelmente evitando fazer uma chamada para `ToList()`.

Para pesquisar você pode fazer com o input e um botão parar disparar e usar o valor do input para pesquisar em seguida define novamente o `DataSource`, por exemplo:

```
gridView.DataSource = banco.ObterProdutos().Where(m => m.Produto.StartsWith(valordoinput);
gridView.DataBind();
```

A parte chata vai ser manter a busca e o sort juntos. Você precisaria criar um método que vai buscar o SortExpression de cada uma das colunas do gridView assim como a expressão de pesquisa que retorne uma lista de produtos com `Where` e `OrderBy`.

Comment: Parece que essa é a maneira mais prática de se fazer isso. Eu gostaria de evitar refazer a consulta, visto que se eu tiver uma quantidade de dados muito grande, vai demorar mais para eu fazer a busca e a ordenação (nem tanto a busca). A alternativa seria usar `Session` ou `ViewState` (que seria uma alternativa pra manter a busca e o sort juntos também), porém guardar uma grande quantidade de dados aí não seria muito bom também.

Comment: Então, manter no ViewState carrega o cliente que pode ficar pesado, manter em Session carrega o IIS. Eu penso em projetos web, diferente do que seria com desktop, deixar essas tarefas a cargo do servidor SQL acaba sendo a forma menos custosa, já que o um SGDB é otimizado para responder à queries.

Answer (score 0):

Se o Grid já estiver populado você pode usar o próprio ds da grid para retomar as informações sem a necessidade de buscar novamente na base.. Acredito que isso daria certo..

```
 IList<seuObj> variavel = this.GridView1.DataSource as IList<seuObj>;

 if (variavel != null){
     GridView1.DataSource = variavel.OrderBy(x => x.campo).ToList();
     GridView1.DataBind();
 }
```